# Div not respecting height percentage

Tags: html, css

I would like to have an ADS fixed on the right side when landscape (25% width) or on the bottom when portrait (25% height).

Landscape is working fine, but on portrait it's not respecting the 25% of the main div.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main" class="ORIENTATION">
        <div id="queue"></div> <!-- 75% -->
        <div id="ads"></div> <!-- 25% -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Landscape Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gmrn24yd/9/

Portrait Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/gmrn24yd/8/

Comment: Hight is getting applied, Just view cutting off, Add `overflow:auto;` to container, you will understand how much portion is getting cutoff.

Comment: @LaxmikantDange Thanks! I got what is happening! How can I force the ads visible all the time with 25% of the main div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with your header, It was taking **70px** and Your `#main` height is **90%**, It can't What if 70px is greater than 10% of the document? It will push other div down and thats why ads portions is getting cutoff. The solution is The height of #main should be based on header aswell. You can use calc function of css to calculate. *Do some RnD and check browser compatibility for this.* [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) is the mdn documentation for calc.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/1mtmuuju/) is the solution of your problem.

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* HEADER */
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  position: relative;
  background: #ed1c24;
  padding: 20px 0;
}

/* MAIN */
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 70px); /*Calculate height based on header*/
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

/* MAIN LANDSCAPE */
#main.landscape {
  display: inline-block;
}

#main.landscape #queue {
  width: 75%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
}

/* MAIN PORTRAIT */
#main.portrait {
  display: block;
}

#main.portrait #queue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 75%;
}

/* LANDSCAPE ADS */
#main.landscape #ads {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  float: right;
  background: #000;
}

/* PORTRAIT ADS */
#main.portrait #ads {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="main" class="portrait">
        <div id="queue"></div>
        <div id="ads"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

He doe's respect the height, it's just you can't see it because his bottom area is out of the body and his position is `fixed`. If you use chrome and you know how to see the width and the height of the element you will see it. Look the images:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: I would like the ads visible all the time. Why it is out of body area?

Comment: Because the node before it `<div id="queue"></div>` has `height:75%`. If you will lower it, You will see the rest of the ads div.

Comment: Queue has 75% of main height and ads 25% (the rest). So both should fit perfect, not?

Comment: I think that your big mistake is that the `#header` has `height:70px` and the `#main` has `height:90%`. Who says that in all the time 70px (+ 20px padding) are 10% percent from the parent height?

Answer (score 0):

I could not see any problem while running this code. Only thing since you have given 100% height and width for the container view is cut off. You can verify the code by providing a fixed width and height for the outer container

Comment: The problem is on the portrait, where the ads div is not respecting 25% of the main div (it's smaller).